# Dropbox integration with auth 2

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, dropbox, dropbox-api

I want to integrate Dropbox using Auth 2 in my website like I call an dropbox api and it will return url of dropbox login and user should enter user name and password after successful it should return access token to access other users dropbox folders and files.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're looking for instructions on how to implement the OAuth 2 app authorization flow for the Dropbox API. You can find the full documentation for the Dropbox API OAuth 2 flow here:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#oauth2-authorize

There's also an OAuth guide that may be useful here:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/oauth-guide

We recommend using one of the official SDKs though, if one is available for your platform:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation

Comment: I want example of integration of dropbox using auth 2

Comment: You tagged your question C#, so I recommend checking out the [.NET SDK samples](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/dotnet).